# Php array of arrays get right result

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I wanna to iterate trought array of arrays.
What i have:

```
$params =  [
 'regs' => [156, 154, 138, 132, 142, 144],
 'axis' => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 'visible' => [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 'dependencies' => [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
];
```

What i want to get:

```
foreach() {
 foreach() {
  render_element(reg = 156, axis = 0, visible = 1, dep = 1);
  *render_element(reg = 154, axis = 0, visible = 1, dep = 1);
  *render_element(reg = 138, axis = 0, visible = 0, dep = 1); etc
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you even bother to check how the foreach loop works? What did you try, what doesn't work? Also, do all subarrays always have the same length? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Could you describe what you are trying to achieve (requirements), what you already tried and what is the error message you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to iterate in the first `regs` array and use the same key to print values from the other arrays since keys looks identical as follow

```
foreach($params['regs'] as $key => $val) {
    echo 'render_element(reg ='. $val.', axis ='. $params['axis'][$key].', visible ='. $params['visible'][$key].', dep ='.$params['dependencies'][$key].');' . "\n";  
}
```

This will print

```
render_element(reg =156, axis =0, visible =1, dep =1);
render_element(reg =154, axis =0, visible =1, dep =1);
render_element(reg =138, axis =0, visible =0, dep =1);
render_element(reg =132, axis =0, visible =1, dep =1);
render_element(reg =142, axis =0, visible =0, dep =1);
render_element(reg =144, axis =0, visible =0, dep =1);
```

[**live demo**](https://ideone.com/hg7tyL)

Comment: You could do it with a 
`for($i=0; $i<count($params['regs']);$i++){ 
$params[regs[$i]; 
$i++;
}` as well

Comment: Yes you could also do that way

Comment: Thanks! Just couldn't beat that simple thing :(

Comment: You are welcome dude

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure, that all arrays in params have equal length you can use a regular for loop:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($params["regs"]); ++$i)
{
    render_element($params["regs"][i],
    $params["axis"][i],
    $params["visible"][i],
    $params["dependencies"][i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heii MaoStrean

Check the syntax of the foreach-loop: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php